# TFS client options outside of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Are there any TFS client options that do not involve Visual Studio? I'm at an MS shop but we want to be able to version everything include Excel spreadsheets and Access databases (etc, etc). I am surrounded by a bunch of Excel macro jockeys and they want to version all their spreadsheets (and included macros). Can TFS handle this with a machine that won't have Visual Studio installed?

Yes, I realize that TFS may not be ideal, but it's the hand I'm dealt. So, please, no, "why not use X instead" answers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use TFS for source control with Access and Excel.

Install [Team Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30656) (Team Explorer is the client software that you use to access the Team Foundation Server functionality.)

Install [Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b5b5053e-af34-4fa3-9098-aaa3f3f007cd)

Then you will need to install the extensions for your Office application.

For [MS Access 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6840)

Comment: Thats a very interesting solution, thank you. The last link says that its a general source control connector, not specific to TFS per-se. Do you know if that will also connect to SVN? I'm assuming it would.

Comment: @JimBeam If there's a MSSCCI provider for Subversion then it would work, but I don't think there is.  MSSCCI is a deprecated system that only some version control tools support:  Team Foundation Server, Visual SourceSafe, SourceGear Vault, perhaps a few other tools, but support is generally uncommon.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at TF?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413282(v=vs.100).aspx

TFS 2013 also has git integration (so checkin via git clients).  Not sure if that would be an option for you?